# what is the basic concept behind using pen_release in the starting the cpus in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, smp

in linux kernel smp, pen_release identifier is used starting the secondary cpus, also i have found that it is being used in other places as well.

I have checked its values in the sysdump, also tried understanding it with the lauterbach setup but couldn't get the basic concept of using this.

As far as i can understand, its a kind of lock that is used to put the secondary cpu in a loop until we release the pen from primary cpu. I have tried to confirm this understanding by various methods but could not get much.

Can anyone explain this in detail?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is here : http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0425/ch04s07s01.html

While the primary core is booting, the secondary cores are held in a standby state, using the WFI instruction. The primary core provides a startup address for the secondary cores and wakes them using an *Inter-Processor Interrupt* (IPI), an SGI signaled through the GIC. Booting of the secondary cores is serialized, using the global variable pen_release. Conceptually, you can think of the secondary cores being in a holding pen and being released one at a time, under the control of the primary core. 
The variable pen_release is set by the kernel code to the ID value of the processor to boot and then reset by that core when it has booted. When an inter-processor interrupt occurs, the secondary core checks the value of pen_release against their own ID value by using the MPIDR register.
Booting of the secondary core proceeds in a way similar to the primary core. The secondary core enables the MMU. It enables the interrupt controller interface to itself and calibrates the local timers. It sets a bit in cpu_online_map and calls cpu_idle(). The primary processor can detect the setting of the appropriate bit in cpu_online_map and set pen_release to the next secondary core.

Some more info here :
http://elinux.org/images/0/00/Clement-smp-bring-up-on-arm-soc.pdf

You can see the code for mach-vexpress. Four functions are called in this sequence for the smp initialisation :
1) smp_init_cpus 
2) smp_prepare_cpus
3) smp_boot_secondary
For mach-vexpress the function is versatile_boot_secondary() which writes the pen_release using write_pen_release(cpu_logical_map(cpu));
Then sends an IPI arch_send_wakeup_ipi_mask(cpumask_of(cpu));
4) smp_secondary_init
e.g versatile_secondary_init() function again makes the pen_release as -1

Isn't this how the primary CPU initializes/starts the secondarys

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. can you explain a bit more on the second para?

Comment: Edited to include mach-vexpress functions